# When to use a Component Instance instead of a Component?

Tags: reactjs

Is there any difference, apart from the function (that makes the component) being called again, between rendering a Component and a *Component Instance*?

Consider this snippet:

```
// component.jsx
function Foo() { return <div/> }
function Bar() { return <div><Foo /></div> }

// component-instance.jsx
const icon = <Foo />

function Foo() { return <div/> }
function Bar() { return <div>{fooInstance}</div> }
```

I'm thinking there might be a performance difference between the two, especially if `Bar` gets rendered (called) often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, what you're calling a component instance is usually called a [React Element](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html).

The only downside of using Elements instead of Components is that you won't be able to update its props.

The performance gain from not calling a function to generate the element is neglible, you shouldn't really bother trying to optimize here.